# Ember.js pass arguments to action helper

Tags: ember.js

How do I pass "simple" arguments to an action helper for example:

```
<li><a {{action markRead true target="controller"}}>Todo</a></li>
```

True would be the argument I want to pass.

This obviously does not work.

Does it have to be an ember path for this to work?

Comment: Not sure if it doesn't take values like this, but IMO I think you'd be better off having that property in the controller or the model and have `markRead` act as a toggle on that property, so instead of passing a simple value you'd pass the item as the context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In recent versions of Ember (certainly >= 2.0), your example would be written as:

```
<li><a {{action "markRead" true target="controller"}}>Todo</a></li>
```

and true would be a boolean as you want it to.

Older versions of Ember would interpret `true` as a property path and attempt to resolve it's value.

Comment: Y not the action helper can support passing arguments to the target eventhandler ?  Is it is intentional ??? @Luke

Comment: It supports passing property values as arguments. So each argument will be interpreted as a property path that will be resolved to it's underlying value and then passed to the target with the action.

Comment: This answer is not any more valid. Check [@kabal's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21612052/316700)

Comment: Thanks. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

maybe this has been added to ember.js recently, but you most certainly can pass parameters in action helpers

template:

```
{{action "downloadVideo" this false}}
```

route:

```
var ApplicationRoute = FooRoute.extend({

   actions: {
      downloadVideo: function(video, closeModal) {
        console.log("closeModal", closeModal); //outputs "closeModal false" if this didnt work it would output "closeModal undefined"
      }
   }
});
```